# Can $\pi$ be rational in some base radix

Tags: number-theory, pi, number-systems

I am from a physics background and my mathematics is not very good, so pardon my insolence with the question.

Editing based on the comments :
We know that $\pi$ in decimal (i.e. base 10) is transcendental. **Is it possible to have a radix base in which $\pi$ can be rational in that base ?**

PS : My question is in general for any transcendental number.

Comment: The rationality of a number does not depend on the base in which it is represented.

Comment: Rational numbers are ratios of integers. This definition makes no mention of bases.

Comment: Since the rationality of $\pi$ is not a matter of its representation, perhaps you should instead pursue the topic of whether a radix base can be irrational.

Comment: I don't know about transcendental radices, but one can speak of using the Golden Ratio (which is irrational but not transcendental) as a radix, and this choice has some special properties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base .

Comment: Base doesn't determine rationality. It does determine whether the base $x$ expansion repeated. For instance, in base $\pi$, $\pi$ is $10$.

Comment: So that means, I think that answers my question that $\pi$ can indeed be rational in some base !!

Comment: No. $\pi$ can have a finite representation in certain bases, such as base $\pi$. But $\pi$ remains an irrational number.

Comment: No. No, no, no, it can't be rational, no way. How many "no" answers would be enough to convince you, really?

Comment: And this is why I like the analogy of numbers=points in manifolds, numerical bases=coordinate charts.

Comment: Ok Ok, so being rational is defined only with respect decimal number system ? I am sorry, am not able completely understand that

Comment: By definition, a real number $x$ is rational if there exist integers $p, q$ such that $x = p/q$. If there are no such integers then that is the definition of $x$ being irrational. Notice this definition says nothing about the base used for a representation of $x$ and the rationality of $x$ is therefore independent of any such base. The proof(s) of the irrationality of $\pi$ also do not rely (and cannot rely) on the base used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're getting confused on the difference between a representation that does not terminate, a number being irrational, and a number being transcendental.

Whether the representation terminates depends on the base. For example, in base $10$, this does not terminate: $$\frac{1}{3} = 0.3333333333333\ldots$$ But in base $3$, we have $$\frac{1}{10} = 0.1.$$

There is some overlap, but this is is separate concept from irrational numbers. We say a number $x$ is rational if there are integers $a$ and $b \neq 0$ such that $$\frac{a}{b} = x.$$ If there are no such integers, then the number is irrational. It doesn't matter if the representation is terminating or non-terminating in a given base, as long as the integers $a$ and $b$ exist, the number is rational.

One-third is a rational number, because we can use $a = 1$ and $b = 3$ (to use the most obvious choice, there are others, of course), and this even though its representation in base $10$ does not terminate.

But $\pi$ is irrational, though it can be approximated well enough (in a purely practical sense) with rational numbers. Its representation will not terminate in any integer base. I would even go so far as to say that the only way for $\pi$ to have a terminating representation in base $x$ is for $x = n \pi$, where $n$ is a nonzero integer.

I could be wrong about that last bit, but the fact remains that $\pi$ has no truly precise representation as a ratio of two integers. In general, any irrational number represented in an integer base will have a non-terminating representation.

As for transcendental numbers, I will just say that all transcendental numbers are irrational and thus any transcendental number represented in an integer base will have a non-terminating representation.

Comment: You can get a terminating expansion for $\pi$ in lots of bases that are algebraically related to $\pi$, not just its multiples. For example, $\pi$ is $110$ in base $x=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{4\pi+1}-1) \approx 1.3416$. (You can find this number by solving the equation $x^2+x=\pi$.)